# How do I get AttributeData from AttributeSyntax in Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

Question as in the title.

From an object of type `AttributeSyntax` how can I get the related `AttributeData` representation in order to access the metadata?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to find the `ISymbol` that the syntax is applied to, call `GetAttributes()`, and find the returned `AttributeData` for which `ApplicationSyntaxReference` matches your `AttributeSyntax`.

Comment: How do you get the ISymbol for attribute?

Comment: @Andez: The semantic model should have APIs to get the symbol for the AttributeSyntax.  You can use the Syntax Tree Explorer to see which node & which API.

Answer (score 4):

@SLaks [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28949920/213871) is correct. Here is some code to retrieve attributes from a `AttributeListSyntax`:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Collections.Generic;

static class Extensions
{
    public static IReadOnlyList<AttributeData> GetAttributes(this AttributeListSyntax attributes, Compilation compilation)
    {
        // Collect pertinent syntax trees from these attributes
        var acceptedTrees = new HashSet<SyntaxTree>();
        foreach (var attribute in attributes.Attributes)
            acceptedTrees.Add(attribute.SyntaxTree);

        var parentSymbol = attributes.Parent!.GetDeclaredSymbol(compilation)!;
        var parentAttributes = parentSymbol.GetAttributes();
        var ret = new List<AttributeData>();
        foreach (var attribute in parentAttributes)
        {
            if (acceptedTrees.Contains(attribute.ApplicationSyntaxReference!.SyntaxTree))
                ret.Add(attribute);
        }

        return ret;
    }

    public static ISymbol? GetDeclaredSymbol(this SyntaxNode node, Compilation compilation)
    {
        var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(node.SyntaxTree);
        return model.GetDeclaredSymbol(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for assembly-level symbols. For those, use `Compilation.Assembly.GetAttributes()`.